# Click only selects one of class

Tags: jquery, html

alright, so i've been modifying my site to allow for more data records to be reached per "event". everything was working great until I decided to actually add a secondary record to the database. Now when i open up my content box and click on an "Event" i can only select 1 of the items there.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#body').load('body.php', function(){
    $('.stars, .ship').click(function(){
                        var name = $(this).attr('name');
                        var type = $(this).attr('type');
                        var linkvar = 'content.php?eid=';
                        var link_full = linkvar + name;
                        $('#box').show('slow');

                        $('#box_content').addClass(type);

                        $('#box_content').load(link_full, 
                            function() 
                            {
                            $(function(){ $('#close_this_box').click(
                                function(){
                                        $('#box').hide('slow');
                                        })
                                    });
                            $('.event').click(function() 
                            {
                                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                                var linkvar = 'content.php?cid=';
                                var link_full = linkvar + name;
                                $('#loading').show();
                                $('#box_content').load(link_full, 
                                function()
                                    { 

                                    });
                            });
                            });
                    });});
```

(http://gmz1023.com/index.php for the live view; the site is too dynamic to actually add a jsfiddle, i appoligize for that.)

Comment: This has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: I don't even recall posting it to PHP.

Answer (score 2):

This is a CSS problem.
Your "box_footer" is overlapping your table.

Tip: Rethink your javascript structure to use jQuery.on method to add events to elements.